# Cannot use letter x to start html attribute in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I noticed something very strange about Angular 1.5.6 components. I have a component called scale. I call it:

```
<scale x-scale="xScale"></scale>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.xScale = 'lin'.
```

And my component definition:

```
angular
    .module('myapp')
        .component('scale', {
            templateUrl: 'analyse/components/scales/scale.tpl.html',
            controller: function(){
                console.log('in controller and this is ', this);

            },
            bindings: {
              xScale: '='
            },
    });
```

The console log outputs undefined.

But if i change `x-scale` to `r-scale` in my template and `xScale` in the binding to `rScale`, suddenly it works. In fact it seems that if i replace the x with any other letter, it works. Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for directives

> **Normalization**
>
> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name
>   to determine which elements match which directives.
>   We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel).
>
> However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> 1. **Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.**
> 2. Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_` -delimited name to camelCase.

So Angular strips of `x-` from the front of any attribute name to normalize it, this is done because both regular data-attributes, starting with `data-`, and x-attributes, starting with `x-` is valid in HTML 5.

The [HTML5 specification](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html) states that

> Attribute names beginning with the two characters "`x-`" are reserved
>   for user agent use and are guaranteed to never be formally added to
>   the HTML language.

It also states that

> For markup-level features that are intended for use with the HTML
>   syntax, extensions should be limited to new attributes of the form
>   "`x-vendor-feature`", where vendor is a short string that identifies the
>   vendor responsible for the extension, and feature is the name of the
>   feature.

The `x-` attributes aren't used very often, but as noted above they are reserved for browser vendors, and you shouldn't be using them, instead you should be using data-attributes, where incidentally, Angular will also remove the `data-` part for you, so these

```
<scale data-scale="scale"></scale>
<scale x-scale="scale"></scale>
<scale scale="scale"></scale>
```

are all the "same" when you do

```
$scope.scale = 'lin'.
```